# When rotating, objects jump around the screen

Tags: modeling, transforms

[image]

I don't know if this is related at all, but before when I was rotating the object strechted while rotating. Like the z axis scaled higher but everything else didn't. While rotating.

The half of an arm I'm manipulating has multiple children and is a child to the upper half of the arm.

EDIT: It was jumping around because some parts of it were overlapping with the main body mesh and collision was enabled so it jumped around. I'm still having the problem of scaling when I rotate the mesh. I can't find anything online, so I think I'm gonna rotate it so I have the scale I want then join all the different meshes together into one character mesh.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Verify you have no snapping enabled.

Comment: No, but I sort of fixed the issue. I added an edit above.